# Create an array of objects per each contestant by using the data stored in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to create an array of objects per each contestant by using the data stored in a text file which includes the details of the 20 contestants. The project is created in IntelliJ and is a Java Project.

The Text File Looks like this ;

> Tom Solesbury ;Molesey BC ;26  ;01:29.4 ;02:58.7 ;04:28.0 ;05:58.3
>
> Marcus Bateman ;Leander Club ;24 ;01:28.9 ;02:58.9 ;04:29.2 ;05:58.2
>
> Evgeni Trofimov ;Marine Technical Uni Russia ;35   ;01:28.2 ;03:01.3
> ;04:34.5 ;06:02.0

```
String filePath = "birc.txt";
        String line ;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(";", 7);

            name = parts[0];
            club = parts[1];
            age = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            fiveHundred = Time.valueOf(parts[3]);
            thousand = Time.valueOf(parts[4]);
            thousandFiveHundred = Time.valueOf(parts[5]);
            twoThousand = Time.valueOf(parts[6]);

            Rower rower;

                rower = new Rower();
                rower.setName(name);
                rower.setClub(club);
                rower.setAge(age);
                rower.setFiveHundred(fiveHundred);
                rower.setThousand(thousand);
                rower.setThousandFiveHundred(thousandFiveHundred);
                rower.setTwoThousand(twoThousand);

                rowerDetails[next[0]++] = rower;


        }
        reader.close();
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Answer (score 0):

this here is not correct:

```
String line = "";

String[] split = line.split(";");

name = split[0];
club = split[1];
```

since line is an empty string, split will be init with an empty array.

reading the 1st element or second will cause an exception

Comment: Still, it's not working and gives the error in the BufferedReader Line